# How to stretch the background image inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

HTML:

```
<div class="navImageLinks">
    <div id="fp" class="mainImageNav floatLeft fp">
        <img src="../theImages/FindaProvider_icon.png" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> Find a Provider
    </div>
    <div id="sv" class="mainImageNav floatLeft sv">
        <img src="../theImages/Services_icon.png" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> Services
    </div>
    <div id="lc" class="mainImageNav floatLeft lc">
        <img src="../theImages/Locations_icon.png" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> Locations
    </div>
    <div id="ma" class="mainImageNav floatLeft ma">
        <img src="../theImages/MakeAnAppt_icon.png" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> Make an Appointment
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navImageLinks
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.mainImageNav
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: small;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.fp
{
    background: url('../theImages/FindaDoc_NotActive.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.sv
{
    background: url('../theImages/Services_NotActive.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.lc
{
    background: url('../theImages/Locations_NotActive.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ma
{
    background: url('../theImages/MakeAnAppt_NotActive.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

IE (zoomed out):

[image]

Firefox (zoomed out):

[image]

How can I edit my CSS so the background also stretches in IE?

Comment: I would assume you mean ie8? background-size is not supported. I've seen a bloated polyfil around. Do it the old fashioned way, before background-size, with sprites if you need to make it look good in IE8

Comment: It is the same in IE 9/10... When I zoom out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this using the new css3 background size property.

```
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

In IE cover backgrounds work using the following css properties.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Refer to the following article to explore other interesting methods for doing the same:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: `background-size` [does not require prefixing in any browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). The `filter` approach is only needed for IE8 and below, so most likely unnecessary for any realistic current project. Keep your code clean.

Comment: Cover i tested and doesn't fill the bottom and leaves a little space

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge in what browser are you facing this issue?

Comment: IE 9 and IE10. It is weird because I thought IE10 would be good with the code but I guess it is not :/

Comment: Try adding background property with the following attributes. background:url('image.png') no-repeat center center fixed;

Comment: Did you try adding the above property?